# Jasper-reports : getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports, outputstream, illegalstateexception

In my java web application I want to print the information of a user when I enter his id, I used the plugin jasperreport with netbeans, the problem is that when I compiled and previewed the report it worked, but when I used my page html I had an empty page and this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

page.html

```
  <form action="info.jsp">
   <input type="text"  name="id" >
  </form>
```

info.jsp

```
  <body>
    <% 

  int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("//info.jasper"));
Map param=new HashMap();
param.put("id", id);
 byte[]bytes=JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(),param,conn);
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");
  response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
  ServletOutputStream outStream=response.getOutputStream();
  outStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
  outStream.flush();
  outStream.close();
  }catch(Exception ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
  }      

    %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: I saw the other answers but it didn't work for me, here the list of libraries which I downloaded:
 `jasperreports-6.0.4.jar
 jasperreports-font-6.0.4.jar
 jasperreports-javaflow-6.0.4.jar
 barecode4j-2.1.jar
 commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar
 commons-codec-1.5.jar
 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
 commons-digester-2.1.jar
 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
 iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
 com-jaspersoft-ireport.jar `

Comment: All the answers tell to use a servlet. JSP is a HTML code producer. You want to produce a PDF file, not a HTML file with PDF content inside. If you absolutely insist in abusing a JSP for this, then remove ALL characters outside `<% %>`, otherwise JSP would write them anyway via `getWriter()`. As told in those answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used a servlet but I had an empty page,  I have a question, I used JSP and I tried to print the list  of the   users   and it worked very well, the problem is that   I want to print  the information of a particular user by entering his id.

Comment: @BalusC I changed and I used a servlet, the problem is when I want the list of users, it works very well but if I want to print a particular user I had an empty page ?